# Is there a metatime required for space-time to change?

Tags: spacetime, time

Space-**time** is thought to curve and ripple. Is a kind of metatime required in or during
which such events take place?

Answer (score 2):

> Space-time is thought to curve and ripple.

Space-time, i.e. the set of all events under consideration (specificly: coincidence events), together with all relations between these events (primarily: by listing who, among all principal identifiable participants, took part any one coincident event), is thought to be not necessarily homogenous and/or isotropic by definition, but (possibly) to consist of distinct regions which (may) differ in terms of suitable measures, such as curvature.

> Is a kind of metatime required in or during which such [differences and distinctions] take place?

**No:** at least some measures of (possible) differences are defined **intrinsically**, appealing **only** to participants and the coincidence events in which they took part. Some examples are sketched

- [here ("Which causal structures are absent from any “nice” patch of Minkowski space?")](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/66636/which-causal-structures-are-absent-from-any-nice-patch-of-minkowski-space) and
- [here ("Can the vanishing of the Riemann tensor be determined from causal relations?")](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/66412/can-the-vanishing-of-the-riemann-tensor-be-determined-from-causal-relations).

Answer (score 0):

This is an open problem, the problem of Time in General Relativity and Quantum Gravity (e.g [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.2157) and [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20181222171212/http://www.ens-lyon.fr/DSM/SDMsite/M2/stages_M2/Geiller.pdf)).

The solution would require a (radical) synthesis of General Relativiy, Quantum Field Theory and especially Thermodynamics (the 2nd Law).

Many people, due to the treatment of *time* parameter in general relativity (general covariance principle), take a stance that *(flow of) time is an illusion* (sth this author does not agree with).

Another approach is to interpret the *time* parameter in General (and Special) Relativity as *duration time* and **not** as *event instant time*, this provides a workaround for many cases.

Furthermore [work by Prigogine and others](http://www.mountainman.com.au/ilyatime.htm) has [shown](https://doi.org/10.1126/science.201.4358.777) that in non-linear systems one can define a unique Liouville-type operator which is not-time symmetric and which can define a (new) unique time-parameter for the dynamic evolution of the system ([Prigogine's lecture on the Nobel prize](https://www.nobelprize.org/uploads/2018/06/prigogine-lecture.pdf)).

> The  problem  of  time  in  physics  and  chemistry  is  closely
> related  to  the  formulation  of  the  second  law  of
> thermodynamics.  Therefore  another  possible  title of  this  lecture
> could  have  been: “the macroscopic and microscopic aspects of the
> second  law  of  thermodynamics”. It  is  a  remarkable  fact  that
> the  second  law  of  thermodynamics  has  played in  the  history  of
> science  a  fundamental  role  far  beyond  its  original  scope.
>
> Suffice it to mention Boltzmann’s work on kinetic theory, Planck’s
> discovery of quantum theory or Einstein’s theory of spontaneous
> emission, which were all  based  on  the  second  law  of
> thermodynamics.

Comment: Nikos, isn't it obvious that time is not a "point", just like distance is not a point? Still, it seems the problem of time required for the space(time) to change boils down to the question: what is the speed of gravity? Here is an interesting answer: http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/5502/43402

Comment: @brightmagus, nice link, but the problem of time is more than the velocity of gravity and in the final analysis is a problem in whole physics theories (not just gravity). It manifests in gravity due to general covariance principle in space-time, but it is still there anyway

Comment: @brightmagus, however if that is what the OP asks for, i would add this as an answer or a comment to the answer (if i were you). i think the OP asks sth a bit more general but the OP will decide for himself

Comment: OK, there are two ways to establish the time the OP is asking about. Either we need first to understand the mechanism of space(time) change (how is the change occurring exactly, what is changing and how), and then verify it empirically, or simply conduct some experiment to get the number only (without understanding). The link I gave speaks of the attempts to measure the speed of gravity, and if gravity is curvature, then measuring its speed should give us (some) answer as to the time needed for this change to occur. (True, the OP was not very specific.)

Comment: Hi @NikosM., several links in your answer are dead now.

Comment: @Urb,  updated all links I could find, except one

Comment: @NikosM., thanks. I've updated the missing link with the copy archived by the Wayback Machine.

Comment: @Urb, why the downvote?

Comment: The downvote's not mine. The edits have caused this question to be on the homepage now, so it may have attracted views from other users.