# Which is more fundamental,''constancy of speed of light'' or ''space-time''?

Tags: speed-of-light, relativity

My friend asked me,''which is more basic or fundamental? constancy of speed of light which makes space-time behave dynamically OR dynamical behavior of space-time that makes light to travel with constant speed? I think 1st one because space-time is just a human-created model...''?

I answered ,''space-time is more fundamental ,because speed of light is constant only locally,where space-time can be taken as flat ,so constancy of speed of light is a property of space-time ,so space-time is more fundamental(?).''

he replied,''speed of light is always constant ,its only different in different coordinate system''.

So what should be the correct ans?

Answer (score 2):

It is an artificial distinction to say one is more fundamental than the other. The geometry of flat spacetime is given by the Minkowski metric:

$$ ds^2 = -c^2dt^2 + dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2 $$

and this is fundamental in the sense that all of special relativity is described by this equation. But it is also fundamental that the parameter $c$ in the equation (which is of course the speed of light) is a constant. So you can't say the geometry is more fundamental than the constancy of the speed of light or *vice versa*.

This applies to general relativity as well, because even when spacetime is curved the local spacetime geometry is approximately flat.

Answer (score 2):

Which is more fundamental is probably a meaningless question, but you can think of the geometric notion of a *manifold* (the mathematical abstraction of spacetime) as being more *general* than Lorentzian manifolds, *i.e.* ones whose metric is locally like that given in [John Rennie's Answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/178618/26076). So one could in principle conceive of universes that were described by non-Lorentzian manifolds or even by more general geometric objects than manifolds, such as [varieties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_variety). But the constancy of the speed of light encodes what I would call *essential* symmetries of *our particular* universe as I discuss in my answers [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/143421/26076) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/165530/26076). I would call these are *essential* symmetries because a universe without them would be radically different from ours: possible lack of causality is one striking possibility.

I'm not a big fan of science fiction, but the SciFi author Greg Egan in his "Orthogonal" series does a most wonderful job of exploring one such universe, where the manifold is not locally Lorentzian (*i.e.* all inertial observers measure $c$ to be the same) but Euclidean. The physics in such a universe is very weird indeed, and Egan gives a primer to Orthogonal on his website [here](http://gregegan.customer.netspace.net.au/ORTHOGONAL/00/PM.html) where he compares how simple physical principles would change.