# Why does adding kinematical conditions between the coordinates prevent the Riemannian line element to "preserve the Euclidean structure"?

Tags: classical-mechanics, differential-geometry

I was reading *Kinetic Energy and Riemannian Geometry* in *The Variational Principles of Mechanics* by *Cornelius Lanczos*; here is the concerned excerpt:

> Let us define the line-element of a $3N$- dimensional space by the equation: $$\overline{\mathrm ds}^2 = \sum_{i\,=\,1}^Nm_i~(\mathrm dx_i^2 + \mathrm dy_i^2 + \mathrm dz_i^2)\tag{15.11}$$
>
> [...] The form of the line-element $(15.11)$ of $3N$-dimensional configuration space of $N$ free particles has a Euclidean structure, and that the quantities  $$\sqrt{m_i}x_i~~~ \sqrt{m_i}y_i~~~\sqrt{m_i}z_i $$ have to considered rectangular coordinates of that space.
>
> If the rectangular coordinates are changed to arbitrary curvilinear coordinates according to the transformation equations $$x_1= f_1(q_1,q_2,\ldots, q_n),\\ .......................\\ .......................\\ z_N= f_{3N}(q_1,q_2,\ldots, q_n),\tag{12.8} $$ the **geometry remains Euclidean**, although the line-element is given  by the more general Riemannian form: $$ \overline{\mathrm ds}^2 = \sum_{i, \, k\,= \,1}^n g_{ik}~\mathrm dx_i\mathrm dx_k$$ with $n= 3N\,.$
>
> Let us now consider a system with  *given kinematical conditions* between the coordinates. We can handle such a system in two different ways. We may consider once more the previous configuration space of $3N$ dimensions but restrict the free-movability of the C-point by the given kinematical conditions which take the form $$f_1(x_1,\ldots, z_n) = 0,\\  ..................\\ f_m(z_1,\ldots, z_n)= 0\,.\tag{15.15}$$ Geometrically, each one of these restricting equations signifies a curved hyper-surface of $3N$-dimensional space. The intersections of these hyper-spaces determines a subspace of $3N-m= n$ dimensions, in which the C-point is forced to stay. This subspace is **no longer a flat Euclidean but a curved Riemannian space.**
>
> Another way of attacking the same problem is to express from the very beginning the rectangular coordinates of the particles in terms of $n$ parameters $q_1\ldots,q_n\,.$ These parameters are now the curvilinear coordinates of an $n$-dimensional space whose line element can be obtained by differentiating each side of $(12.8)$ and substituting them in the expression  $(15.11)\,.$ The line-element takes the form: $$\overline{\mathrm ds}^2 = \sum_{i, \, k\,= \,1}^n a_{ik}~\mathrm dq_i\mathrm dq_k\,.\tag{15.16}$$ The $a_{ik}$ are here given the functions of the $q_i\,.$ The line element is now truly Riemannian not only because the $q_i$ are curvilinear coordinates, **but because the geometry of the configuration space does not preserve the Euclidean structure** of the original $3N$-dimensional space, but in *infinitesimal regions*.

I couldn't comprehend the above marked statements:

From $(15.11),$ the author concludes that the $3N$-dimensional space is *Euclidean*. Then transforming the coordinates to *generalised coordinates* $q_1,\ldots, q_n,$ he told the line-element $ \overline{\mathrm ds}^2 = \displaystyle\sum_{i, \, k\,= \,1}^n g_{ik}~\mathrm dx_i\mathrm dx_k$ develops again the *Euclidean Geometry but the line-element being in the more general Riemannian form.*

$\bullet$ How does the line-element $ \overline{\mathrm ds}^2 = \displaystyle\sum_{i, \, k\,= \,1}^n g_{ik}~\mathrm dx_i\mathrm dx_k$  develop Euclidean Geometry as stated by the author? For the line-element to be developing Euclidean geometry, the $\mathrm dx_i\mathrm dx_k$ terms must not be there, isn't it?

---

In the very next para he worked on a system with *given kinematical conditions between the coordinates* and got the form of the line-element as:

$$\overline{\mathrm ds}^2 = \sum_{i, \, k\,= \,1}^n a_{ik}~\mathrm dq_i\mathrm dq_k\,.$$

He asserted the line-element $(15,16),$ above, is purely Riemannian and it does not develop the Euclidean Geometry since "**the geometry of the space *doesn't preserve the Euclidean structure***".

$\bullet$ Notice both the line-elements viz.  $ \overline{\mathrm ds}^2 = \displaystyle\sum_{i, \, k\,= \,1}^n g_{ik}~\mathrm dx_i\mathrm dx_k$ and  $ \overline{\mathrm ds}^2 = \displaystyle\sum_{i, \, k\,= \,1}^n a_{ik}~\mathrm dq_i\mathrm dq_k$ are in the *general Riemannian form* and looking almost alike.

Still, the former preserves the Euclidean Geometry while the latter develops geometry which does not "*preserve the Euclidean structure of the $3N$-dimensional space*".

Why is it so? Why does, by introducing *kinematical conditions between the coordinates*, avert the line-element $\overline{\mathrm ds}^2 = \displaystyle\sum_{i, \, k\,= \,1}^n a_{ik}~\mathrm dq_i\mathrm dq_k$ *unlike* $ \overline{\mathrm ds}^2 = \displaystyle\sum_{i, \, k\,= \,1}^n g_{ik}~\mathrm dx_i\mathrm dx_k$ to **preserve the Euclidean Structure**?

Of course, I wouldn't expect same behaviour from both cases as the first one deals with free-particles while the second one deals with a system with *given kinematical conditions* i.e., constraints.

But, I'm not getting, in spite of appearing to be exactly same, why the first line-element can develop the Euclidean Geometry while the second one not.

Could anyone shed light on this?

---

I have discussed about this in the chat where [John Rennie](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/1325/john-rennie) put forth:

> The curvature is coordinate independent, so it does not depend on the choice of coordinates. $^\S$
>
> Yes. Starting from a flat space it's possible to choose curved coordinates in which the metric doesn't look like a Euclidean metric. However the apparent curvature is due to your choice of coordinates and not a property of the space. $^{\S\S}$

I thought if that is so, then it seems pretty okay to me for the first case as the $3N$ dimension was Euclidean while after transforming the coordinates to generalised one, the line-element $\overline{\mathrm ds}^2 = \displaystyle\sum_{i, \, k\,= \,1}^n g_{ik}~\mathrm dx_i\mathrm dx_k$ also develops Euclidean Geometry.

But for the second case, the author explicitly mentioned the line-element $\overline{\mathrm ds}^2 = \displaystyle\sum_{i, \, k\,= \,1}^n a_{ik}~\mathrm dq_i\mathrm dq_k$ didn't develop Euclidean Geometry not due to just the curvilinear coordinates:

> The line element is now truly Riemannian **not only because the $q_i$ are curvilinear coordinates**, but because the geometry of the configuration space **does not preserve** the Euclidean structure of the original $3N$-dimensional space.

That's the thing I didn't get why it didn't preserve the Euclidean structure "*even though curvature is coordinate dependent*".

Where am I misinterpreting and mistaking?

---

<sup>$^\S$ [Link I](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/71?m=32392188#32392188)</sup>

<sup>$^{\S\S}$ [Link II](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/71?m=32392210#32392210)</sup>

Comment: Comment to the post (v1): Consider to double check for $x\leftrightarrow q$ typos, and $3N \leftrightarrow n$ summation limit typos.

Comment: @Qmech, Are you talking about $(12.8)\,?$ I would read between the lines then.....

Comment: No, eq. (12.8) is OK.

Comment: Exactly, @Qmech, where did I mess up? I know $n$ is not same in the two cases. Hmmm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lanczos is essentially saying that if one imposes constraints on a $3N$-dimensional [Euclidean space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_space) (which is an [affine space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space) with an Euclidean metric of Euclidean signature), one gets (under certain regularity assumptions) an [embedded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedding) $n$-dimensional [submanifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submanifold), with the [generalized coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_coordinates) as local coordinates. The submanifold inherits a [Riemannian metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_manifold) by [pullback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback) from the ambient Euclidean space. Be aware that the word *Euclidean* has different meanings in mathematics and physics, cf. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/47950/2451).