# What's the difference between locally Lorentzian and locally Euclidean?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

What's the difference between locally Lorentzian and locally euclidean? Was the former (Lorentzian) the hyperbolic surface restriction of the latter (Euclidean)?

Comment: Is this from a reference? Which page?

Comment: @Qmechanic I'm reading Gravitation chapter 13 the metric, where the concept of local Lorentz came up and a simple (necessary but not sufficient) criterion. I got curious, and started thinking, I mean, could the geometry resolve one of the sign change in the euclidean norm by itself?

Comment: @Qmechanic The concept first came up at track 1 page 20 box 1.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [pseudo-Riemannian manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Riemannian_manifold) $(M,g)$ is locally Euclidean (Lorentzian) if the metric tensor $g$ has positive (Minkowski) signature, respectively.

NB: Concerning the use of the word *Euclidean,* see also my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/47950/2451).