# Is there any physical interpretation of Nash embedding theorem?

Tags: general-relativity, classical-mechanics, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, topology

Nash embedding theorem says that every Riemannian manifold can be (isometrically) embedded into $R^n$. That means that every $RM$ is a sub-manifold to $R^n$.

Since General Relativity is defined on a pseudo-Riemannian manifold and classical theories are defined on a "simple" Euclidean space, I want to ask what the embedding theorem means for the relation between GR and classical physics.

Comment: The embedding is not unique, though, and it would change dynamically (including the necessary embedding dimension!) as the manifold changes. How do you interpret that?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8932/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/267916/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 3):

Spacetime in General Relativity is not Riemannian so surely it can't be embedded isometrically in $\mathbb R^n$. I suppose it might be possible to embed it in some $\mathbb R^n$ with different signature. However, I don't see any relevance. This is merely a mathemathical fact. Our world is not a differential manifold after all.

Comment: Ok, I did not know that it would be relevant if its a Riemannian or an Einsteinian manifold. But a pseudo-riemannian-manifold is still a differentiable manifold (with a tensorial function defined over it), or isnt it ?

Comment: Yes it is. However it is not a Riemannian manifold so Nash's theorem doesn't strictly apply. There is Whitney's theorem which says that every manifold can be embedded in some $\mathbb R^n$, but it says nothing about the question whether the embedding can be made isometric.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But, in that way, the Einsteinian Manifold could be embedded in euclidian space, even if not isometrically ?

Comment: Any Lorentzian manifold of signature $(1,3)$  can be embedded in ${\mathbb R}^{252,252}$ (that is, ${\mathbb R}^{504}$ with signature $(252,252)$).

Comment: @WillO where did you get these numbers from?

Comment: @Blazej:  I haven't double checked but I'm pretty sure you can find them here:  http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1969-75-06/S0002-9904-1969-12407-9/S0002-9904-1969-12407-9.pdf

Comment: The general bound is $(n(2n+1)(2n+6)/2,n(2n+1)(2n+6)/2$ for a Lorentzian manifold of dimension $n$.